# Fastest way to get frames from video in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I encounter a problem recently. I want to get some frames form a video in mp4 format. I am using opencv3. My code is as below:

```
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, ind)
ret, img = video.read()
```

And I found video.set() function is time costing. It running times varies from 20ms to 120ms.
But I want to read 7 frames at a total time below 100ms, is it possible? Is it possible under python?
PS. Speed is really all that matters. I'm not fixated on OpenCV. Whatever works best.
Thank you!

Comment: jumping in videos is often expensive because encoders often only represent frames as differences from previous frames. So to extract a single image, you often have to decode multiple frames, starting from the last keyframe before the wanted image.

Comment: @Micka Tanks for your answer, thus I know why it is slow. So I decide to avoid jumping between frames. This really works. Thank you.